# Bottom-up approach to minimum number of coins for change

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change, bottom-up

I am constructing a bottom-up approach to the coin change problem. I have to give the minimum number of coins needed to give the change requested. It may be possible that the change could not be given because the given denominations cannot form the value.

For example, it the given denominations are {4, 8} and they ask for a change of 5 then it is impossible to give 5. I constructed the program below and it works well for most situations unless it is impossible to form the requested change. For example, when the denominations is just {4} and I request 5, it returns one which is false. What can I do to correct this problem?

Here P represents the change requested,
S are the number of denominations stored in the array denominations[] from index 0 to S - 1. dp is a two dimensional array for calculation initialized to -1.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= P; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < S; ++j) {
        int ans, x, y;

        // Min. no. of coins with current coin
        x = (i - denominations[j] >= 0) ? dp[i - denominations[j]][j] + 1: 0;

        // Min. no. of coins w/o current coin
        y = (j > 0) ? dp[i][j - 1] : 0;

        ans = min(x, y);
        if (ans == 0) ans = max(x, y);
        dp[i][j] = ans;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: One key thing is to define what you want `dp[i][j]` to mean, e.g. "`dp[i][j]` will be the minimum number of coins required to make a total of `i` using only coins of type <= `j`".  I can tell that the first subscript refers to the total value, but I can't tell what the second subscript is supposed to be.  Also it seems you aren't allowing for multiple coins of the same type.

Comment: The second subscript, j, refers to the jth denomination. One can actually take the multiple coins of the same time as dp[i][j] means we are deciding on whether or not to take the coin with jth denomination when we have i value left.

Comment: I realise that in some vague sense the second subscript "refers to the jth denomination", but you need to tell me exactly what you expect the expression `dp[a][b]` to mean, if it appeared in the first line of the innermost loop body.  You can assume a <= i and b <= j.

Comment: dp[a][b] means the minimum number of coins you can use to form the value a with the first j elements of the denominations set. 
For example given denominations = {1, 2, 4}, then dp[4][1] = 2 since you can form the value 4 by using 2 and 2 (you cannot use 4 since it is the 2nd element counting from 0), and this is the minimal number of coins you can use.

Comment: It seems your dp[a][j] is the min no. Of coins needed upto j with a value <= a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is that you aren't correctly handling the case when it is forbidden **both** to use the current coin, **and** not to use it.  This occurs in your example case, for instance: when i=1 and j=0, we are trying to make a total of 1c using either nothing or just a 4c coin; but we can't do this with a 4c coin, and we can't do it without a 4c coin either.

In such cases, both x and y will be assigned 0, and the line `if (ans == 0) ans = max(x, y);`, which is designed to catch the case when *either* of the possibilities are forbidden, winds up incorrectly assigning 0 to ans.  Later iterations of the outer loop will consequently "think" that it is possible to make the corresponding sum for a total of no coins whatsoever, and blithely add 1 to this, giving the incorrect answer of 1 for your example.

The cleanest fix, I think, is to choose a different sentinel value than 0 to represent "This action is impossible and should not be considered".  Since you're combining the two possible actions with `min()`, an extremely high value fits naturally:

```
#define INF (INT_MAX-1)   // Or anything higher than the biggest sensible answer

for (int i = 0; i <= P; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < S; ++j) {
        int ans, x, y;

        // Min. no. of coins with current coin
        x = (i - denominations[j] >= 0) ? min(INF, dp[i - denominations[j]][j] + 1) : INF;

        // Min. no. of coins w/o current coin
        y = (j > 0) ? dp[i][j - 1] : INF;

        ans = min(x, y);
        dp[i][j] = ans;
    }
}
```

Notice how the line `ans = min(x, y);` now gives the right answer without further work, including the case where it should be `INF` because both x and y are `INF`.

A more subtle point is that when we *read* some `dp[a][b]` during our calculations, **that value is allowed to be `INF`**: this is a legitimate value, indicating that `a` cents can't be made with any combination of coins of type <= `b`.  Ideally, the value chosen for `INF` would have the property that adding or multiplying it with any positive value leaves it at `INF`, since then we wouldn't have to make any further adjustments to this algorithm: every operation we perform on an `INF` value would correctly leave it at `INF`.  But integer arithmetic doesn't work that way, so after adding something to a value that could be `INF` we need to check that we haven't "gone past infinity" and fix it up if so: that's why `d[i - denominations[j]][j] + 1` is wrapped in a `min(INF, ...)` call.  (This is also why I defined `INF` to be one less than `INT_MAX` -- so that overflow can't occur.)